# How do you prevent appending html multiple times in BS modal divs in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Whenever I click on an image, a modal box should pop up with an appended paragraph once. I have two issues. Firstly, my header text doesn't append to the header element. Secondly, it keeps appending the same paragraph into the modal box every time I click the laptop.

HTML

```
<!--Trigger Image -->
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/02-512.png" id="laptop" class="openmodal">

<!--Modal Box -->
<div class="question" id="question-modal">
  <header id="modal-header">
    <a href="#" class="close">X</a>
  </header>
  <div class="answer">
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var id = this.id;

//Open the modal box
$('.openmodal').on('click', function() {
  $('#question-modal').modal('show');
  if (id == 'laptop')
    $('header').append('<h3>FAQs on laptops</h3>');
    $('.answer').append("Mac > any PC");
});

//close modal box
$('.close').on('click', function() {
  $('#question-modal').modal('hide');
});
```

Here's my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5522LLLz/) if that description wasn't clear.

I'm not sure as how to temporarily remove the paragraph when you close the box. I tried .remove() but when the laptop is clicked, the paragraph is removed completely (well no duh). .detach() doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the desired behavior correctly, then I believe you are looking for `.empty()`

In your close modal callback, try adding:

```
$('.answer').empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change modal box onclick to this:

```
//Open the modal box
$('.openmodal').on('click', function() {
    $('#question-modal').modal('show');
    if (this.id == 'laptop')
    $('header'). append('<h3>FAQs on laptops</h3>');
    $('.answer').empty();
    $('.answer').append("Mac > any PC");
  });
```

And empty should be in open modal. Otherwise if modal still open on click will add additional paragraph